# IllegalStateException when using ViewPager without Fragments

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am using `ViewPager` to swipe between images.My `ViewPager` does not use any `Fragment`. When i swipe to next image my app crashes and exception occurs in `instantiateItem()`.Here is my adapter class:

```
public class SlidePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
Context context;
int[] mResources = {
        R.drawable.sports1,
        R.drawable.sports2,
        R.drawable.sports3,
};

public SlidePagerAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
    mLayoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager, container, false);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager_image);
    imageView.setImageResource(mResources[position]);

       container.addView(imageView);           // HERE MY APPLICATION CRASH
    // container.addView(imageView, position); 
    return imageView;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == object;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mResources.length;
}

@Override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
    container.removeView(((View) object).getRootView());
}
}
```

Here are the logs details:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a
>   parent.You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3938)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3788)
>       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addView(ViewPager.java:1413)
>       at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3729)
>       at mycompany.microfinance.SlidePagerAdapter.instantiateItem(SlidePagerAdapter.java:37)
>       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.addNewItem(ViewPager.java:943)
>       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1157)
>       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1025)
>       at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager$3.run(ViewPager.java:254)
>       at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:767)
>       at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:580)
>       at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:549)
>       at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:753)
>       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5343)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:905)
>       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:700)

I am not getting how to resolve it.I followed a tutorial and i think i was following it right.Please help me found out where i am doing it wrong.Thanks.

Comment: onDestroyItem, just remove `object`.

Comment: FWIW, [here is a sample activity](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/ViewPager/MultiView1/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/mvp1/MainActivity.java) that implements a fragment-less `ViewPager`. As Mr. Spitsin notes, your problem is with the parallelism in your `addView()`/`removeView()` calls. Those need to match; yours do not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call `container.removeView(((View) object))` not `container.removeView(((View) object).getRootView());`

The problem is, as I understood, that you can not add view that is already added, because you didn't delete it, you tried to delete its parent

Also, please, provide this.

```
@Override
public int getItemPosition(Object object){
    return PagerAdapter.POSITION_NONE;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object){
    return view.equals(object);
}
```

**Updated**

I just realised, that your problem in this part:

```
View itemView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.viewpager, container, false);

ImageView imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.viewpager_image);
imageView.setImageResource(mResources[position]);

container.addView(imageView);
```

If `imageView` is some sub view in inflated `itemView` then you have a problem, because you try to add `imageView` to `container`, but it already has parent `itemView`. So or you need to add not `imageView`, but `itemView` to `container`, or you need to think about your inflation.

Comment: @andy Did you saw my last update about `instantiateItem` method?

Answer (score 0):

this condition should be working, if your other code works fine!

```
if(imageView.getParent()!=null)
    ((ViewGroup)imageView.getParent()).removeView(imageView); // <- fix
layout.addView(imageView);
```

Comment: This is not a fix, since removeView must be called in `destroyItem` method, and author calls it, but unfortunatelly not for view, but for some rootView.